# Finding out how my location is being gathered. Force close on Location.getProvider();

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to check where my GPS service is getting the provider from, when GPS is off. I have it set up to Go GPS>network>Default which I assume is wifi.

A little while ago when I set the location setting on my Nexus 5 to battery saving, it couldn't find my location at all in Google maps or my app. Even though it clearly says for Network/Wifi. I have since changed it back to High Accuracy, still a force close.

Anyway does anyone know how I can find out where my location is coming from, either GPS, network or Wifi? First off the phone doesn't have a network (no sim card) so that's out.

I keep getting a force close when trying to do location.getProvider(); I assume that's because it is returning null. Locat below.

```
if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())) {
            Log.i("TAG", "GPS");    
        } else if (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.equals(location.getProvider())) {
            Log.i("TAG", "NETWORK");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("TAG", "NEITHER");
}

02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395): Process: com.package.name, PID: 3395
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at com.package.name.MapsPage$runGet.onPostExecute(MapsPage.java:535)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at com.package.name.MapsPage$runGet.onPostExecute(MapsPage.java:1)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-24 17:26:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see I'm running it in the onPostExecute of a server call as the very first thing.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there a better way to call it possibly? I'm initiating the GPS finder as a service, if it fails it looks for a network, if it fails that goes to Wifi (Or at least I presume); The logcat barely provides me with any information.

Would really appreciate some help on this, thanks!

**Edit:**

```
public class MapsPage extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
}

/*LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};*/
}
```

Commented out the the bit below because of the error I was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning this are native methods from the gps provider and you can implement them in your project...

```
     @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);// here you will see gps or network in your logcat
    }
}
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

02-24 11:28:29.722  16488-16488/com.solmoviles.tmp E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS﹕ onProviderDisabled: gps
```

02-24 11:28:29.790  16488-16488/com.solmoviles.tmp E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS﹕ onProviderDisabled: network
02-24 11:28:29.790  16488-16488/com.solmoviles.tmp E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS﹕ onProviderDisabled: gps

**EDIT** here is the full code of the class where I get the location

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }
        @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, is the code not up to date? I get the impression the public voids should have be inside a method. Just like an OnClickListener is.

Comment: Yeah I understood in the end. I tried it in my Service and my MapsPage but nothing showing in my log. I also get 'Cannot instantiate the type LocationListener' This is in the botttom with mLocationListeners.

Comment: I wold like to let you know that this code is implemented into a service... so it may look a little bit triky for you... but there you can see the important code where you catch the info you are looking for...

Comment: Thing is I've tried that, I'll show you the code for that, it's essentially identical.

Comment: Nothing in the service showed up either. I used this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: are you getting the coordinates??

Comment: I'll keep looking but you've have given me quite a few ideas via the LocationListener. I want it to check if the order in the service works. So I can always check that by going outside... I haven't logged coordinates, I did earlier and I got them. I just don't want you spend loads of time on it! Like I said, it's purely to test something else in the app. Not actually a feature.

Comment: Glad to help... if you want you can upvote the answer or either acept it... regards!!

Comment: HAHA. My service just kicked inand now it's constantly telling me onStatusChanged: gps. What timing! Guess I just needed a few moments for it to do a proper search.

Comment: that's actually the behavior that you were looking for dont you??? well I'm glad you got your app to work...

Comment: Yeah exactly what I wanted, and exactly as you described. Thanks once again.